# Как вырезать ненужную часть в строке

Tags: javascript

У меня есть строка `"watch?v=xL-a5Tox7Qw&t=964s"` мне нужно от этой строки убрать `watch?v=` чтобы осталось только `xL-a5Tox7Qw&t=964s` как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Заменой подстроки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) - либо буквально, со строковым литералом (при этом будет заменено только первое вхождение); либо по регулярному выражению (когда оно с флагом `g`, заменяются все вхождения):

```js
console.log(
  'watch?v=xL-a5Tox7Qw&t=964s'.replace('watch?v=', '')
);
console.log(
  'watch?v=xL-a5Tox7Qw&t=964s'.replace(/watch\?v=/gi, '')
);
```

*// Флаг регулярки `i` - задействует регистронезависимую проверку соответствия.*

Comment: благодарю, помогло!